I can't figure out what the error is, when applying migration on the django server, I'm trying to connect a PostgreSQL database
the error looks like this:
Unable to connect to PostgreSQL: 
Traceback (most recent call last):`your text`
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()`your text`
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\python\SkillFactory\Sprint\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\python\SkillFactory\Sprint\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 436, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\python\SkillFactory\Sprint\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 412, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\python\SkillFactory\Sprint\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 458, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\python\SkillFactory\Sprint\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 106, in wrapper
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\python\SkillFactory\Sprint\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 117, in handle
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
  File "C:\python\SkillFactory\Sprint\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "C:\python\SkillFactory\Sprint\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 58, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "C:\python\SkillFactory\Sprint\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 235, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "C:\python\SkillFactory\Sprint\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 81, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "C:\python\SkillFactory\Sprint\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 57, in has_table
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "C:\python\SkillFactory\Sprint\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\python\SkillFactory\Sprint\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 330, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "C:\python\SkillFactory\Sprint\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\dummy\base.py", line 20, in complain
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.

the settings file with a fragment of the database settings looks like this
load_dotenv()

print("Database Name:", os.getenv('FSTR_DB_NAME'))
print("Database User:", os.getenv('FSTR_DB_USER'))
print("Database Password:", os.getenv('FSTR_DB_PASSWORD'))
print("Database Host:", os.getenv('FSTR_DB_HOST'))
print("Database Port:", os.getenv('FSTR_DB_PORT'))

BASE_DIR = Path(file).resolve().parent.parent
# Настройки базы данных
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': os.getenv('FSTR_DB_NAME'),
        'USER': os.getenv('FSTR_DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.getenv('FSTR_DB_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': os.getenv('FSTR_DB_HOST'),
        'PORT': os.getenv('FSTR_DB_PORT'),
    }
}

I also have a file.an env that contains all the data that is needed to connect.
I must say right away, I need to get the data through the environment variables. I have never encountered this and have never worked with it, if there are any sources that talk about it, I will only be glad if someone gives me a link that tells me how to do everything right.

Use django-environ for managing environment variables: https://django-environ.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html

Did you install the psql connector?

@Niko, there is no psql connector as that is the CLI client that ships with Postgres. You are looking for the Python Postgres driver.

Your error django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured is triggered because Django cannot find or properly interpret the settings specified in your project configuration files.
In this case, it appears your specified database engine in the Django settings does not match the actual database being used. Please verify and align the database engine configuration.
For managing environment variables, I use python-decouple which is quite effective.
